# Msi is over write installation directory

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-installer

**I try to install Mysql.msi file in the F:\ drive using command below command:**
$msiexec /a mysql-commercial-8.0.27-winx64.msi INSTALLDIR="F:", /qn, /l*v, install.log

**In the MSI log file, I found the path changed automatically.**

MSI (s) (E4:18) [14:37:45:516]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying INSTALLDIR property. Its current value is 'F:'. Its new value: 'C:\MySQL\MySQL Enterprise Backup 8.0'.

*Note:I am facing this issue in Azure and GCP server alone not in AWS windows server.*

Comment: try to replace INSTALLDIR with TARGETDIR="F:"

Comment: HI Christophe, Thanks for your update but it is also not working. Start-Process -FilePath msiexec -ArgumentList "/a mysql-commercial-backup-8.0.27-winx64.msi TARGETDIR=`"F:`"", /qn, /l*v, "install.log" -wait